# Nexus 4 , Galaxy Nexus AVD - Landscape not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am trying to test my app on different devices and am having problems with the Nexus 4 and Nexus Galaxy Emulators. They are doing the opposite of what I expect them to do, they are locking in portrait instead of landscape.

```
<activity
    android:name="org.myApp.Main"
    android:screenOrientation="userLandscape"
```

I have tested on devices and emulators for Nexus 7,10 and 1 and they are all fine.

Is this a problem with the emulator or are these devices different. Unfortunately I do not have a device available now to test on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried changing to Landscape rather than userLandscape and it seem ok now.
    android:screenOrientation="landscape"

My problem was my AVD  was running API 17 and user userLandscape Is 18

SensorLandscape is best for me.

Comment: David I had to mark my own answer as correct since it gave more detail. But thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for this piece of information. It was really useful, I have not realized what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

You can test with

```
 android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

and see here differences between userLandscape and landscape :

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#screen

Comment: David you answered at the same time as me. Landscape does work but not sure why user landscape does not  "userLandscape" Landscape orientation, but can be either normal or reverse landscape based on the device sensor and the user's sensor preference. If the user has locked sensor-based rotation, this behaves the same as landscape, otherwise it behaves the same as sensorLandscape. Added in API level 18.

Comment: I will try sensorLandscape